# Laravel Relationship HasManyThrough

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm having trouble setting up a relationship within my application using Laravel/Eloquents relationship syntax.

I have:

`Events`
   - id, name, location

`Reservations`
   - id, event_id, user_id

`Users`
   - id, name, etc

and I want to be able to grab "All users objects across all reservations for a given Event". I have tried using `hasManyThrough` with the various argument sets to get this result set, but am coming up with empty sets!

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Use many to many relation in this scenerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `users` table should have `reservation_id` foreign key of reservations table if you are looking for `hasManyThrough` relationship.

If you need to obtain

> All users objects across all reservations for a given Event

You could use

```
$users_with_reservation = Reservation::where('event_id', $event_id)->pluck('user_id');

$users = User::whereIn('id', $users_with_reservation)->get();
```

Comment: Fantastic, I didn't know about the whereIn function, that's really nice for doing subsets. Thank you for your time and insight!